# Writing a batch to run mutiple commands?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run multiple commands in a BAT file, but it is only running the first one, and then stopping. This is what I have:

```
cmd /k "reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP /f"
cmd /k "reg delete HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\SAP /f"
cmd /k "RD /S /Q C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\SAP /f"
cmd /k "RD /S /Q C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\SAP /f"
cmd /k "RD /S /Q C:\Program Files\SAP /f"
cmd /k "RD /S /Q C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP /f"
```

It runs the first command successfully then stops.

Comment: Don't use `cmd /k` and remove the quotes around the commands.

Comment: It's also best to quote paths.

Comment: Why don't you just run the official SAP Uninstall script?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the `cmd /k` part. Did you try this way?

```
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP /f
reg delete HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\SAP /f
RD /S /Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\SAP" /f
RD /S /Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\SAP" /f
RD /S /Q "C:\Program Files\SAP" /f
RD /S /Q "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP" /f
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply removing the instances of `cmd /k` would be the biggest improvement for your script. *This version however makes a few less important improvements.*

```bat
@Echo Off
Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\SAP" /F>Nul
Reg Delete "HKU\.DEFAULT\Software\SAP" /F>Nul
RD/S/Q "%LOCALAPPDATA%\SAP"
RD/S/Q "%APPDATA%\SAP"
RD/S/Q "%PROGRAMFILES%\SAP"
RD/S/Q "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\SAP"
```

Comment: In addition, `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local` can be replaced with `%LOCALAPPDATA%`.